# General link field value reverting on save

Tags: content-editor

This is Sitecore 9.0.2, and I do not have any custom item:saved/item:saving pipelines going. On this template, in only one particular field (a general link field), if I make any change to the field (such as clearing it, changing the link, etc), when I save the value reverts to the existing value. This happens if I clear the field from the raw values as well. This is not happening on any other field in the item/template.

Comment: Can you check logs?

Comment: Is this field compulsory to have a value?
Check if there is any default value set or not?

Comment: The field used to be Shared, right?  and now isn't,  Or used to be in a different shared/versioned/unversioned state before than it is now, right?

Comment: @MarkCassidy That's correct, it used to be shared, and now it isn't. I'm noticing this issue doesn't occur in my local instance, but does in our Azure environments.

Comment: Run Control Panel > Cleanup Databases - then try again

Comment: @MarkCassidy Did that, but I'm seeing the same result.

Comment: Oddly, this article solution seems to have worked: https://codeandlearnspot.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/modifying-field-value-shared-versioned-database-get-corrupted/. Basically it suggested "flushing" the problem child field by setting it shared, then unchecking it again. I did it on a QA environment and it cleared up.

Comment: Yea. There's a longer behind the scenes discussion to be had on what goes on in Sitecore when you change field sharing. I know there's an answer on this site even that explains it. Will link it to this question, once I have time to find it.

Comment: I got the same issue during the deployment of changes of Shared/Unversioned values in the template. As this question hasn't had an answer, I have provided a description of a solution that helped me. Thank you for the comments above.

Comment: I have the same issue, but Anton's solution did not work. Did you find any other solution? Bahaviour: https://gfycat.com/tinypolishedantelopegroundsquirrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the same issue, but with other field types.

**Steps how I reproduced the same issue:**

1. We have Unicorn serialization
2. We have automated deployment of Unicorn
3. I changed few(but it could be even one) types. The field was *Shared*, I ticked off the shared checkbox.
4. Changes were deployed (Unicorn sync and then publish)

After these steps, it became impossible to change and save the value in the field.
But you can get the same issue with other steps, e.g. installation of the package, where the field was not *Shared* (but was *Shared* before). And the same issue could happen when you modify *Unversioned* checkbox on the template.

**How to fix this problem:**

**Option 1: Fix with template manipulations**

1. Backup your solution
2. Open template that was changed
3. Manually set *Shared* and *Unversioned* checkbox values that were before you got this issue
4. Save and publish the template
5. Manually set *Shared* and *Unversioned* checkbox values to desired state
6. Save and publish the template

**Option 2: [Follow Sitecore KB article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/045873)**

1. IMPORTANT! Back up your solution.
2. Copy the Sitecore.Support.310642.dll assembly to the /bin folder.
3. Copy the Sitecore.Support.310642.config file to the /App_Config/Include folder.
4. Copy the FixFieldSharing.aspx file to the /sitecore/admin folder of your solution.
5. Request the /sitecore/admin/FixFieldSharing.aspx URL and run the fix process for each of the affected databases.
6. Remove all the files added in the previous steps.